# Enable recently used on Gtk3 file chooser

Tags: gnome, gnome3, mate-desktop, gtk3

I can no longer see "recently used" in my GTK3 File Chooser Dialog.

How can I put it back?

Answer (score 3):

It has been removed in GTK3. Please add a comment at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781819
The more people do that, the better the chances might be that the devs bring it back and make it a configurable option.